# Who all is back question

Tags: slang

> Who all is back?

It's a cue from a dialogue. The character asks another about the people invited back to the team. I googled the phrase and found a news post titled "Stranger Things Cast Reunion Video: Who All Is Back for Season 4?" on imdb.com. Is it slang?

Comment: It's an American regionalism.  You might find this useful: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/what-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to be back

is an informal, but perfectly acceptable (at least in the U.S.) synonym for

> to return.

It is not slang.

In both cases, the meaning is the same. Which members of the previous team are on the current team? Which members of the previous season's cast are members of this season's team?

Comment: Yes, but... _Who all_ is very unidiomatic to me. I would expect "Who's back?"

Comment: It may be an Americanism. It means "who, out of all of them,." It is not asking for some, but for all.

Comment: It is definitely an Americanism, primarily found in the South and South Midland.  There's a good discussion of *who all says this?* here: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/what-all